# Why does using .sort() on MongoDB cursor result in this strange error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following JavaScript:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/forex-backtesting';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    var cursor = db.collection('datapoints').find({}).sort({timestamp: 1});

    function next(error, dataPoint) {
        if (!dataPoint) {
            return;
        }

        console.log(dataPoint.data.timestamp);
        cursor.nextObject(next);
    }

    cursor.nextObject(next);
});
```

With 6000+ documents in my "datapoints" collection. When I run this, I get the following error:

```
/Users/chad/development/desktop/forex-backtesting/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'timestamp' of undefined
    at next (/Users/chad/development/desktop/forex-backtesting/mongodb.js:13:35)
    at handleCallback (/Users/chad/development/desktop/forex-backtesting/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
    at /Users/chad/development/desktop/forex-backtesting/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:666:5
    at handleCallback (/Users/chad/development/desktop/forex-backtesting/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:249:5)
    at nextFunction (/Users/chad/development/desktop/forex-backtesting/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:755:5)
    at /Users/chad/development/desktop/forex-backtesting/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:723:9
    at queryCallback (/Users/chad/development/desktop/forex-backtesting/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/wireprotocol/2_6_support.js:105:5)
    at Callbacks.emit (/Users/chad/development/desktop/forex-backtesting/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:95:3)
    at null.messageHandler (/Users/chad/development/desktop/forex-backtesting/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:243:23)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/chad/development/desktop/forex-backtesting/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:262:22)
```

This error consistently occurs on the 708th document.

When I look in the database, I see absolutely nothing wrong with the 708th document (or any surrounding it).

When I do not use `.sort({timestamp: 1})`, however, and I only set `cursor` to `db.collection('datapoints').find({})`, then the problem goes away. Although, even with `.sort({timestamp: 1})` gone, it still hangs on the 708th document for a few seconds, but it moves on without an error.

This problem still occurs -- at the 708th document -- if I drop my database and regenerate all data in my database. The data comes from a CSV file.

Any ideas what's causing this strange error?

Here is the 708th document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("562a3f65097b59cb482440c7"),
    "symbol" : "EURGBP",
    "data" : {
        "timestamp" : 1444063620000.0000000000000000,
        "volume" : 103,
        "open" : 0.7412800000000000,
        "high" : 0.7413000000000000,
        "low" : 0.7411200000000000,
        "close" : 0.7411400000000000,
        "ema200" : 0.7389162677949799,
        "ema100" : 0.7393103557855230,
        "ema50" : 0.7398230887417165,
        "sma13" : 0.7407199999999998,
        "rsi7" : 66.0414114338037450,
        "rsi5" : 65.0646082093880693,
        "rsi2" : 0,
        "prChannel100_2_19" : 0.7411235723937080,
        "prChannelUpper100_2_19" : 0.7423760300257496,
        "prChannelLower100_2_19" : 0.7398711147616663,
        "prChannel100_3_19" : 0.7415269782087759,
        "prChannelUpper100_3_19" : 0.7433692628027987,
        "prChannelLower100_3_19" : 0.7396846936147531,
        "prChannel100_4_19" : 0.7410964752138339,
        "prChannelUpper100_4_19" : 0.7428810720859841,
        "prChannelLower100_4_19" : 0.7393118783416838,
        "prChannel100_2_195" : 0.7411235723937080,
        "prChannelUpper100_2_195" : 0.7424089894371192,
        "prChannelLower100_2_195" : 0.7398381553502967,
        "prChannel100_3_195" : 0.7415269782087759,
        "prChannelUpper100_3_195" : 0.7434177439763257,
        "prChannelLower100_3_195" : 0.7396362124412261,
        "prChannel100_4_195" : 0.7410964752138339,
        "prChannelUpper100_4_195" : 0.7429280351615670,
        "prChannelLower100_4_195" : 0.7392649152661008,
        "prChannel100_2_20" : 0.7411235723937080,
        "prChannelUpper100_2_20" : 0.7424419488484887,
        "prChannelLower100_2_20" : 0.7398051959389272,
        "prChannel100_3_20" : 0.7415269782087759,
        "prChannelUpper100_3_20" : 0.7434662251498525,
        "prChannelLower100_3_20" : 0.7395877312676993,
        "prChannel100_4_20" : 0.7410964752138339,
        "prChannelUpper100_4_20" : 0.7429749982371499,
        "prChannelLower100_4_20" : 0.7392179521905180,
        "prChannel100_2_21" : 0.7411235723937080,
        "prChannelUpper100_2_21" : 0.7425078676712277,
        "prChannelLower100_2_21" : 0.7397392771161883,
        "prChannel100_3_21" : 0.7415269782087759,
        "prChannelUpper100_3_21" : 0.7435631874969063,
        "prChannelLower100_3_21" : 0.7394907689206455,
        "prChannel100_4_21" : 0.7410964752138339,
        "prChannelUpper100_4_21" : 0.7430689243883157,
        "prChannelLower100_4_21" : 0.7391240260393521,
        "prChannel100_2_215" : 0.7411235723937080,
        "prChannelUpper100_2_215" : 0.7425408270825972,
        "prChannelLower100_2_215" : 0.7397063177048188,
        "prChannel100_3_215" : 0.7415269782087759,
        "prChannelUpper100_3_215" : 0.7436116686704333,
        "prChannelLower100_3_215" : 0.7394422877471185,
        "prChannel100_4_215" : 0.7410964752138339,
        "prChannelUpper100_4_215" : 0.7431158874638986,
        "prChannelLower100_4_215" : 0.7390770629637693,
        "prChannel200_2_215" : 0.7402758484187918,
        "prChannelUpper200_2_215" : 0.7410472250445017,
        "prChannelLower200_2_215" : 0.7395044717930819,
        "prChannel200_3_215" : 0.7409437240105643,
        "prChannelUpper200_3_215" : 0.7420799477740195,
        "prChannelLower200_3_215" : 0.7398075002471091,
        "prChannel200_4_215" : 0.7413552860034170,
        "prChannelUpper200_4_215" : 0.7427684526912921,
        "prChannelLower200_4_215" : 0.7399421193155420,
        "prChannel200_2_19" : 0.7402758484187918,
        "prChannelUpper200_2_19" : 0.7409575300880238,
        "prChannelLower200_2_19" : 0.7395941667495598,
        "prChannel200_3_19" : 0.7409437240105643,
        "prChannelUpper200_3_19" : 0.7419478287317572,
        "prChannelLower200_3_19" : 0.7399396192893714,
        "prChannel200_4_19" : 0.7413552860034170,
        "prChannelUpper200_4_19" : 0.7426041309833997,
        "prChannelLower200_4_19" : 0.7401064410234344,
        "prChannel200_2_195" : 0.7402758484187918,
        "prChannelUpper200_2_195" : 0.7409754690793194,
        "prChannelLower200_2_195" : 0.7395762277582641,
        "prChannel200_3_195" : 0.7409437240105643,
        "prChannelUpper200_3_195" : 0.7419742525402098,
        "prChannelLower200_3_195" : 0.7399131954809188,
        "prChannel200_4_195" : 0.7413552860034170,
        "prChannelUpper200_4_195" : 0.7426369953249782,
        "prChannelLower200_4_195" : 0.7400735766818559,
        "prChannel200_2_20" : 0.7402758484187918,
        "prChannelUpper200_2_20" : 0.7409934080706150,
        "prChannelLower200_2_20" : 0.7395582887669686,
        "prChannel200_3_20" : 0.7409437240105643,
        "prChannelUpper200_3_20" : 0.7420006763486622,
        "prChannelLower200_3_20" : 0.7398867716724664,
        "prChannel200_4_20" : 0.7413552860034170,
        "prChannelUpper200_4_20" : 0.7426698596665566,
        "prChannelLower200_4_20" : 0.7400407123402775,
        "prChannel200_2_21" : 0.7402758484187918,
        "prChannelUpper200_2_21" : 0.7410292860532062,
        "prChannelLower200_2_21" : 0.7395224107843774,
        "prChannel200_3_21" : 0.7409437240105643,
        "prChannelUpper200_3_21" : 0.7420535239655671,
        "prChannelLower200_3_21" : 0.7398339240555615,
        "prChannel200_4_21" : 0.7413552860034170,
        "prChannelUpper200_4_21" : 0.7427355883497136,
        "prChannelLower200_4_21" : 0.7399749836571204,
        "prChannel250_2_19" : 0.7399942439157653,
        "prChannelUpper250_2_19" : 0.7407661078034555,
        "prChannelLower250_2_19" : 0.7392223800280751,
        "prChannel250_3_19" : 0.7407271980980636,
        "prChannelUpper250_3_19" : 0.7416439761851809,
        "prChannelLower250_3_19" : 0.7398104200109464,
        "prChannel250_4_19" : 0.7411221890038713,
        "prChannelUpper250_4_19" : 0.7421451989932646,
        "prChannelLower250_4_19" : 0.7400991790144780,
        "prChannel250_2_195" : 0.7399942439157653,
        "prChannelUpper250_2_195" : 0.7407864200110263,
        "prChannelLower250_2_195" : 0.7392020678205042,
        "prChannel250_3_195" : 0.7407271980980636,
        "prChannelUpper250_3_195" : 0.7416681019243155,
        "prChannelLower250_3_195" : 0.7397862942718118,
        "prChannel250_4_195" : 0.7411221890038713,
        "prChannelUpper250_4_195" : 0.7421721203087750,
        "prChannelLower250_4_195" : 0.7400722576989676,
        "prChannel250_2_20" : 0.7399942439157653,
        "prChannelUpper250_2_20" : 0.7408067322185972,
        "prChannelLower250_2_20" : 0.7391817556129334,
        "prChannel250_3_20" : 0.7407271980980636,
        "prChannelUpper250_3_20" : 0.7416922276634501,
        "prChannelLower250_3_20" : 0.7397621685326772,
        "prChannel250_4_20" : 0.7411221890038713,
        "prChannelUpper250_4_20" : 0.7421990416242853,
        "prChannelLower250_4_20" : 0.7400453363834573,
        "prChannel250_2_21" : 0.7399942439157653,
        "prChannelUpper250_2_21" : 0.7408473566337388,
        "prChannelLower250_2_21" : 0.7391411311977918,
        "prChannel250_3_21" : 0.7407271980980636,
        "prChannelUpper250_3_21" : 0.7417404791417195,
        "prChannelLower250_3_21" : 0.7397139170544078,
        "prChannel250_4_21" : 0.7411221890038713,
        "prChannelUpper250_4_21" : 0.7422528842553060,
        "prChannelLower250_4_21" : 0.7399914937524366,
        "prChannel250_2_215" : 0.7399942439157653,
        "prChannelUpper250_2_215" : 0.7408676688413096,
        "prChannelLower250_2_215" : 0.7391208189902210,
        "prChannel250_3_215" : 0.7407271980980636,
        "prChannelUpper250_3_215" : 0.7417646048808542,
        "prChannelLower250_3_215" : 0.7396897913152731,
        "prChannel250_4_215" : 0.7411221890038713,
        "prChannelUpper250_4_215" : 0.7422798055708164,
        "prChannelLower250_4_215" : 0.7399645724369261,
        "prChannel300_2_215" : 0.7397144898022052,
        "prChannelUpper300_2_215" : 0.7405948826604870,
        "prChannelLower300_2_215" : 0.7388340969439234,
        "prChannel300_3_215" : 0.7405155200114335,
        "prChannelUpper300_3_215" : 0.7417096475755254,
        "prChannelLower300_3_215" : 0.7393213924473416,
        "prChannel300_4_215" : 0.7410140704454350,
        "prChannelUpper300_4_215" : 0.7423680587210977,
        "prChannelLower300_4_215" : 0.7396600821697723,
        "prChannel300_2_19" : 0.7397144898022052,
        "prChannelUpper300_2_19" : 0.7404925113978961,
        "prChannelLower300_2_19" : 0.7389364682065144,
        "prChannel300_3_19" : 0.7405155200114335,
        "prChannelUpper300_3_19" : 0.7415707955331892,
        "prChannelLower300_3_19" : 0.7394602444896778,
        "prChannel300_4_19" : 0.7410140704454350,
        "prChannelUpper300_4_19" : 0.7422106182239275,
        "prChannelLower300_4_19" : 0.7398175226669425,
        "prChannel300_2_195" : 0.7397144898022052,
        "prChannelUpper300_2_195" : 0.7405129856504142,
        "prChannelLower300_2_195" : 0.7389159939539962,
        "prChannel300_3_195" : 0.7405155200114335,
        "prChannelUpper300_3_195" : 0.7415985659416564,
        "prChannelLower300_3_195" : 0.7394324740812106,
        "prChannel300_4_195" : 0.7410140704454350,
        "prChannelUpper300_4_195" : 0.7422421063233616,
        "prChannelLower300_4_195" : 0.7397860345675084,
        "prChannel300_2_20" : 0.7397144898022052,
        "prChannelUpper300_2_20" : 0.7405334599029325,
        "prChannelLower300_2_20" : 0.7388955197014779,
        "prChannel300_3_20" : 0.7405155200114335,
        "prChannelUpper300_3_20" : 0.7416263363501236,
        "prChannelLower300_3_20" : 0.7394047036727434,
        "prChannel300_4_20" : 0.7410140704454350,
        "prChannelUpper300_4_20" : 0.7422735944227956,
        "prChannelLower300_4_20" : 0.7397545464680744,
        "prChannel300_2_21" : 0.7397144898022052,
        "prChannelUpper300_2_21" : 0.7405744084079688,
        "prChannelLower300_2_21" : 0.7388545711964416,
        "prChannel300_3_21" : 0.7405155200114335,
        "prChannelUpper300_3_21" : 0.7416818771670581,
        "prChannelLower300_3_21" : 0.7393491628558089,
        "prChannel300_4_21" : 0.7410140704454350,
        "prChannelUpper300_4_21" : 0.7423365706216637,
        "prChannelLower300_4_21" : 0.7396915702692063,
        "trendPrChannel200_2" : 0.7402758484187918,
        "trendPrChannel300_2" : 0.7397144898022052,
        "trendPrChannel400_2" : 0.7397545411034007,
        "trendPrChannel450_2" : 0.7396091538488672,
        "trendPrChannel500_2" : 0.7394596028589882,
        "trendPrChannel550_2" : 0.7393828891171719,
        "trendPrChannel600_2" : 0.7392920548747740,
        "trendPrChannel650_2" : 0.7392473208351870,
        "trendPrChannel700_2" : 0.7391674498652786,
        "trendPrChannel750_2" : "",
        "trendPrChannel800_2" : "",
        "trendPrChannel850_2" : ""
    }
}
```

Comment: `sort` doesn't return anythings, it just sorts the array itself.

Comment: But why am I able to iterate 708 times when using `.sort()`.

Comment: Please post the (anonymized) 708th document.

Comment: It's posted in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

use this [**`sort()`**](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#sort) signature

```
var cursor = db.collection('datapoints').find({}).sort([['timestamp', 1]]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persists using this syntax. So now it looks like: `var stream = DataPoint.find({symbol: self.symbol}, null, {timeout: true}).sort([['timestamp', 1]]).stream();`.